# Uniswap Front Runner Scam

Tags: ether, contract-deployment, error, scam, frontrunning

I just found out that I may have been scammed. Yea, I'm fucking silly.

I followed one tutorial and just to test it out I started with a small amount, but now I cannot withdraw or start the bot.

The thing is that I was able to withdraw the balance once. Now, after sending the same balance again to test it further, I am not able to withdraw or start the bot.

I am sure my funds are sadly lost. But I'd like to know why I was able to withdraw them once but not twice.

If anyone wants to dig in, this is the pastebin I took `https://pastebin.com/raw/aLJPrzpR`

Thanks!